# How to get the values from JS in models.py file

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11

How to get the values of JS in models.py file.
I created the model of weather information where current weather fetch from latitude and longitude. I used the api of openweathermap.org but unable to get the data of current location. 
I used the following to code.

**.py file**

```
WEATHER_API_LAT_LON = "%s/weather?appid=%s&units=metric&lat={}&lon={}" % (API, APP_ID)
    @api.multi
    def get_weather_info(self,lat, lon):
        url = WEATHER_API_LAT_LON.format(lat, lon)
        print(url)
```

**.js file**

```
var GetLocation = function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        return navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } 
    else { 
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log(lat);
    console.log(lon);
}
```

From JS get the location and merge to .py model lat and lon.
Anyone can tell how to do this.

Comment: You can do this via ajax call and using controller in py. From py controller pass json request and from that ajax pass your data.

Answer (score 0):

For Odoo 10

*model.py

```
@api.multi
def get_weather_info(self,lat, lon):
    url = WEATHER_API_LAT_LON.format(lat, lon)
    print(url)
    return url
```

*.js

```
// on header
var Model = require('web.Model');
// inside main function
var model  = new Model('model.name').call('get_weather_info',[]).then(function(result){
    console.log(result)
});
```

For Odoo 11

*.js

```
var self = this;
self._rpc({
    model: 'model.name',
    method: 'get_weather_info',
}, []).then(function(result){
    console.log(result)
})
```

pass your lat and lon in the array while calling method in model.py

Comment: No for odoo 11 *.js. It is not working. I got the solution check it.

Answer (score 0):

***.model.py**

```
@api.multi
def get_weather_info(self,lat, lon):
    url = WEATHER_API_LAT_LON.format(lat, lon)
    print(url)
```

***.js for odoo 11**

```
var self = this;
self._rpc({
    model: 'model.name',
    method: 'get_weather_info',
    args: [], //Here you have to pass the arguments using keyword agrs.
}).then(function(result){
    console.log(result)
})
```